# Graphql query result get the same value after updating it on the server Ios

Tags: ios, graphql

I have a `getdriverLocation` query to get lat and long from server [getdriverLocation query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO2qD.png) and I also have `updateDriverLocation` mutation [updateDriverLoacation mutation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwBcl.png).

The problem is when `updatedriverlocation` on the server using mutation it updates successfully and appear in the playground but when I call it from Xcode the query get the old value while app running I should restart the app to update It and this my code to get location

```
func getDriver(driverId:String, completion: @escaping Generalcompletion){
    Network.shared.apollo.fetch(query: GetDriverLocationQuery(input: driverId)) { [weak self] result in
        guard self != nil else {
            return
        }
        switch result {
        case .success(let graphqlResult):
            if let location = graphqlResult.data?.getDriverLocation{
                let lat = (location.latitude as NSString).doubleValue
                let lon = (location.longitude as NSString).doubleValue
                self?.driverLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
                completion(true,nil)
            }
            if let errors = graphqlResult.errors {
                let message = errors.map { $0.localizedDescription }.joined(separator: "\n")
                completion(false,message)
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            debugPrint("Error In get Driver Locations \(error)")
            completion(false,nil)
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in cash policy parameter in the query make him .fetchIgnoringCacheCompletely

```
 Network.shared.apollo.fetch(query: GetDriverLocationQuery(input: driverId),cachePolicy: .fetchIgnoringCacheCompletely) { [weak self] result in
```